# How can I change Table View Controller's type to a regular View Controller?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, storyboard

I followed the "Storyboard tutorial" and made some Table View Controllers; now I want to change one of them to a regular View Controller.

Is there a way to do that without making a new one?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to create a new view controller and drag a tableview into it. Remember to set the delegate and datasource of the tableview to the view controller.

Comment: and click the view controller that you create and and assign the class for it in Identity inspector and then change your Table View controller class as @interface yourTableViewController : UIViewController in .h file with TableView Delegate and DataSource

Answer (score 51):

One option is to edit the storyboard file directly. Navigate to the Storyboard in Finder and open with any text editor. Find the view controller in question and change the node in the xml from `tableViewController` to `viewController`.

This saves the pain of having to recreate the view controller, which comes in handy when you have a lot of connections made. This also works the other way around. If you have a viewController that started out as a plain view controller but you want to turn it into a table view controller you can simply edit the file reversing the node.

Comment: Works perfectly! When you show the Version Editor in Xcode it will show the Storyboard's content as XML, so you don't even have to open it in a new editor.

Comment: This tip saved me hours of development!

Comment: The accepted answer will work of course, but this one is quick and painless.  Thanks @nortchuck

Comment: you can also right click in Project Navigator -> open as -> source code, to open in Xcode

Comment: And once you have done this... back in IB: cut the root tableview, drag in a new view in the root then paste the tableview into that new root view.

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same scenario where I needed to change the Tableviewcontroller to a view controller. I googled for a work around but ended up without an exact solution. What I did was added a subclass of view controller and dropped a UITableview and added some more controls that I wanted. Pretty inconvenient but worked the way eventually!